# How to get the value of nested object in my java bean?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, javabeans

I need to display `billingAddress` info that is a bean of my primary `CustomerJ` object.

I did not found the syntax how to display `billingAddress.address1` and so on.....

**JRXML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- Created with Jaspersoft Studio version 6.6.0.final using JasperReports Library version 6.6.0  -->
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="pulpshred_invoice" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="ebbcad6c-5106-41cb-964f-6fd5ea27b8ae">
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="One Empty Record"/>
    <subDataset name="Dataset1" uuid="bf97abbf-b160-4edf-b066-3746fc307fed">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
    </subDataset>
    <subDataset name="Dataset2" whenResourceMissingType="Empty" uuid="89cd64cb-59ea-4557-bf42-10b7e21a22a1">
        <queryString>
            <![CDATA[]]>
        </queryString>
        <field name="address" class="java.lang.String"/>
    </subDataset>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="customerId" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="billingAddress" class="java.lang.Object"/>
    <group name="Group1">
        <groupExpression><![CDATA[$F{billingAddress}]]></groupExpression>
        <groupFooter>
            <band height="50"/>
        </groupFooter>
    </group>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <image scaleImage="FillFrame" hAlign="Left" vAlign="Top">
                <reportElement x="60" y="10" width="110" height="40" uuid="c017b894-515d-47f5-a3c0-3c5e23928229"/>
                <imageExpression><![CDATA["http://www.pulpshred.com/images/logo.png"]]></imageExpression>
            </image>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="410" y="5" width="141" height="74" forecolor="#15AB3A" uuid="ff489075-f753-4219-8372-b9c28de85b1c"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[6, 1815-27 Avenue NE
Calgary, AB T2E 7E1
403.453.9009 
info@pulpshred.com
www.pulpshred.com
]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="447" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="40" y="10" width="100" height="30" forecolor="#878677" uuid="42270711-0246-4d09-b669-14d193242303"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="14"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[INVOICE]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="181" y="25" width="130" height="15" uuid="ba506752-394d-4988-871c-dda01f2667d4"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Customer ID/Name]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="181" y="40" width="130" height="15" uuid="af718b31-50a3-4594-8779-928f8e3da762"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Invoice Number:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="181" y="55" width="130" height="15" uuid="6540067a-b64c-4d41-a345-033726b244c8"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Invoice Date:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="181" y="70" width="130" height="15" uuid="5d3ebb96-9951-494f-b1f2-58ff254e9a41"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Service Period:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="181" y="85" width="130" height="15" uuid="f9fcf936-4d48-435b-9778-38bd34bf7a02"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Payment Terms:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="181" y="115" width="130" height="15" uuid="ee090972-2fcf-4e76-972b-55791c761222"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Invoice Receipt Preference:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="181" y="100" width="130" height="15" uuid="29505397-40d9-4740-a99d-89f3adf32df7"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Payment Due By:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="181" y="130" width="130" height="15" uuid="b6551ecc-d3c5-47e5-b6d5-197475f18515"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Payment Method Preference]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="311" y="25" width="234" height="15" uuid="b3b2a4e1-2699-4322-8ae1-42b08b24ce0f"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="4">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="311" y="40" width="234" height="15" uuid="7bffdbf8-9271-42f6-ac9e-baf2da399ab4"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="4">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="311" y="55" width="234" height="15" uuid="5884d3b9-3239-4d2e-af3e-ee5163da3d3b"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="4">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="311" y="70" width="234" height="15" uuid="a0c9a4e0-c3d8-4545-b8d1-76c8002cb717"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="4">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="311" y="115" width="234" height="15" uuid="721b93c4-5673-4d5b-964e-999b84758521"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="4">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="311" y="85" width="234" height="15" uuid="1ab2f0d8-d7c2-44bd-b134-edb62c603c1f"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="4">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="311" y="100" width="234" height="15" uuid="39ac956b-58b8-40ec-ada1-3893e5537ab9"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="4">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="311" y="130" width="234" height="15" uuid="b7f94697-d648-404a-ba33-66fe7dca95ab"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="4">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="311" y="145" width="234" height="15" uuid="eb9bd1fd-04bd-4bae-9848-ea232a657be0"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="0" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="4">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="181" y="10" width="364" height="15" forecolor="#000000" backcolor="#878677" uuid="972ae8ee-1b48-4706-ac91-a4b43a076769"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Account Overview]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="181" y="145" width="130" height="15" uuid="22ee9958-5339-4e19-9abe-061a071a19ec"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[PULP SHRED GST Number:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="551" height="1" uuid="ca671c9b-fbbd-435c-8bc1-b209fb7b2a10"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="240" width="224" height="15" uuid="94506dd4-f4a1-4b1b-a92b-c39e95e2c3f3"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="255" width="224" height="15" uuid="1b7d7169-4819-4206-b64e-32a94080e976"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="110" y="180" width="210" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#878677" uuid="e88d7f5b-9647-4c5c-ac14-a521aaeb656a"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Billing Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="225" width="224" height="15" uuid="df5db5a0-7178-4ff7-9806-25377d2bab05"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="195" width="224" height="15" uuid="4c99c203-8869-49c2-93b5-c9a91668b2c7"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="320" y="210" width="224" height="15" uuid="924ff165-553b-48e0-a5eb-19ae500882a6"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement mode="Opaque" x="320" y="180" width="224" height="15" forecolor="#FFFFFF" backcolor="#878677" uuid="a5300c2f-fcbb-4a5a-8d33-d9497c5236d2"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Service Address]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="240" width="110" height="15" uuid="0f73d450-8813-47d0-a0a5-43f9602d60eb"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Email:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="255" width="110" height="15" uuid="30eb33b7-e913-430f-a73d-077de7301766"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Phone:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="210" width="110" height="15" uuid="7f569af0-955f-4172-8eaf-620007099f16"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Position:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="195" width="110" height="15" uuid="a4f70126-c987-4251-825c-ac25cdce056e"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Contact Person:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="0" y="225" width="110" height="15" uuid="6f57eafd-82e5-4cf8-a0fb-827815cc379d"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="10" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Address:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="255" width="210" height="15" uuid="d93c5453-9007-4e0a-910a-864028cd5f2d"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="225" width="210" height="15" uuid="4f491386-74b6-4746-a959-6a02eee38c2f"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="210" width="210" height="15" uuid="21cb2988-037e-4e93-8abc-ad540e5eb642"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{billingAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="240" width="210" height="15" uuid="6835aecd-7869-4230-8aca-32f4cb266da1"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{customerId}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="110" y="195" width="210" height="15" uuid="fbf1aeb7-a389-4442-9f5e-fbb66b2dd771"/>
                <box topPadding="0" leftPadding="3" bottomPadding="0" rightPadding="0">
                    <pen lineWidth="0.5"/>
                </box>
                <textElement textAlignment="Left">
                    <font fontName="Arial"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{billingAddress}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="58" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="230" y="14" width="135" height="30" forecolor="#009900" uuid="533f1af2-0b39-4d72-8520-08991ffd63ac"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[http://www.pulpshred.com]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

**Java Code:**

```
public  byte[] exportToPdf(String jasperFile,List<CustomerJ> genericReports, Map <String, Object> parameters) throws IOException{
       byte[] jasperPdf =null;
       try {          
            jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperFile);
          //  Map <String, Object> parameters = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            parameters.put("ReportTitle", "User Report");
        //    parameters.put("DataFile", "src/test1.jrxml");
          //  parameters.put("IdRange", 10); 
            JRDataSource reportSource = new JRBeanCollectionDataSource( genericReports);
            jasperPrint = JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, parameters, reportSource);
            jasperPdf = JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdf(jasperPrint);
        //    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jasperPrint, "testing.pdf");
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jasperPdf;
    }
}

public static CustomerJ getCustomer() {
        CustomerJ customerJ =new CustomerJ();
        customerJ.setCustomerId("ALW0003/ALW Partners");
        AddressJ billingAddr = new AddressJ();
        AddressJ serviceAddr = new AddressJ();
        billingAddr.setContactPerson("Jacey Erickson");
        serviceAddr.setContactPerson("Jacey Erickson");
        billingAddr.setPosition("Manager");
        serviceAddr.setPosition("Manager");
        billingAddr.setAddress1("129 17 Avenue NE, Calgary, AB T2E 1L7");
        serviceAddr.setAddress1("129 17 Avenue NE, Calgary, AB T2E 1L7");
        billingAddr.setEmail("JErickson@alw.ca");
        serviceAddr.setEmail("JErickson@alw.ca");
        billingAddr.setPhone("403-230-4660");
        serviceAddr.setEmail("403-230-4660");
        customerJ.setBillingAddress(billingAddr);
        customerJ.setServiceAddress(serviceAddr);
        return customerJ;    
    }
```

Comment: You need to show some jrxml, a small report with your field etc, also the java code that you are using a JRBeanCollectionDatasource?

Comment: @PetterFriberg i have updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two options (I'm not considering that you can create a method on the `CustomerJ` bean):

Define a field and in description indicate path to property.

```
<field name="BillingAddress1" class="java.lang.String">
    <fieldDescription><![CDATA[billingAddress.address1]]></fieldDescription>
</field>
```

**OR**

Define a field as `_THIS` that represents the base class `CustomerJ`

```
<field name="_THIS" class="com.your.package.CustomerJ"/>
```

In expression call methods on that class, as example in textField

```
<textField>
    <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="100" height="20" uuid="5884d3b9-3239-4d2e-af3e-ee5163da3d3b"/>
    <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{_THIS}.getBillingAddress().getAddress1()]]></textFieldExpression>
</textField>
```

Comment: First option worked like a charm. It really helped a lot. Thanks @Petter